# Array of pointers to data members

Tags: c++, arrays, pointer-to-member, data-members

```
class A 
{
    float m_Period; // a1
    float m_Scale;  // a2
};
```

I can have pointer to a data member like this:

```
float A::*pFloat;
```

For reason of handle members in cycle i need an array of such pointers. How to do this.

Comment: Why not just make members `a1`, `a2`, etc into an array, `a` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either `std::vector<float A::*> pFloats;` or, if you need static initialization with the compiler counting the number of initializers, `float A::*pFloat[] = {...};`.

Answer (score 5):

```
typedef float A::*member_t;
```

Now you can declare an array or `vector` of `member_t`.

Comment: You don't need the typedef.  (Depending on use, it might make things clearer.  But this smacks of things like `typedef float* FloatPtr`. Something I'm not a great fan of.)

Comment: True, and not using a typedef "smacks of" `std::vector<void(*)void (A::*)(float[12] &, int(*)(float))>`. Depending on your audience, the complexity of the type, and on how many times you repeat the type in your code, you decide whether or not you want an alias for it.

Comment: Yes.  It's very much a judgement call.  The fact that the declaration doesn't need parentheses makes me lean to not using the typedef, as does the fact that you do need to know that it is a pointer to member of A.  But I probably tend to use such typedef's a lot less than others; if I need a type like yours, I'm more likely to rewrite the code in a way which avoids the type completely.